# Excel 2010 - Pasting as picture without gridlines without having to turn off gridlines setting every time

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I am trying to paste part of a worksheet as a picture into word without gridlines showing. I know that you can uncheck the grid lines check box in the view tab, but I dont want to have to do this every time I copy and past. In Excel 2003, pasting as a picture would automatically paste without the gridlines.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recall the exact behaviour of Excel 2003, but IIRC it only had the Camera Tool to capture and paste sections of a workbook as an image.

In Excel 2010 different method exists: Copy as picture. It is an option in the Copy drop-down on the Home ribbon. Once selected, it will prompt whether the copy should be taken as shown on screen or as shown when printed.

[image]

If your print settings are to suppress grid lines, then selecting the second option will not show any grid lines.

Unless the copied cells have a background color, the pasted picture will have a transparent background. The following screenshot shows the results with the two options (screen/print) and no fill, white fill, and no fill with grid lines unticked.

[image]

The Camera Tool can still be used in Excel 2010. It will show a picture that is linked to the copied cells and will dynamically update when the appearance of these cells change.

So, if you use the Copy as Picture message, select "As shown when printed" to hide grid lines.

Comment: This is one of those features I could have used many times but didn't know existed.  I'm still using 2007 and Microsoft buries this feature in a place nobody would think to look (it took some research to find it).  For anyone else using 2007, this feature isn't under copy, it's under the Paste pull-down arrow.  From there, select As Picture, which opens another dialog window that has the option to Copy as Picture, which then gets you to the dialog window shown in the answer.  Thanks for covering this feature.  Now that I know where to find it in 2007, your explanation is a great education.